# Issue in random generation of arrays with constraint

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

```
Positive_Wt = [0.1,0.3,0.2,-0.6,1] is an example of a vector of size 6.
```

(A) I need to create 10 vectors each of size 6. This is what I did

```
RandVectors = randn(10,6);
```

How do I randomly create such vectors such that the following constraint is met : the fifth element is constrained to have values in between 0 to -1. And the remaining five positive valued weights are constrained to have values 0 to 1.

Comment: How do you constrain a normal distribution? What is the random distribution of constrained elements?

Comment: `Positive_Wt` has 5 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If uniformly distributed variables are a solution for you, just generate uniform values between 0 and 1 and correct the 5th column

```
A = rand(10,6)
A(:,5) = A(:,5) - 1
```

If what you need is gaussian distribution truncating outliers, you can do something like this:

```
A = randn(10,6);
A(A > 1) = 1;
A(A < -1) = -1;
A(find(A(:,1:4) < 0)) = 0
A(find(A(:,6) < 0), 6) = 0
A(find(A(:,5) > 0), 5) = 0
```

Comment: Why should the process be different for the 2 cases of distribution? The answer to one of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337555/issue-in-bounding-values-of-matrix shows how to bound the values which is similar to your second technique when I had created random numbers using rand(). Could you please add some comments to your second part of the answer, as it seems a bit complicated.

Comment: Well it was not clear to me what you need, so I just explored a couple of what I think are "common cases", with uniform distribution data already bounded to those values, or normal distribution. In the second case, which is unbounded, I'm just truncating the values that lie outside the required intervals for each column: none of the values can be above 1 or below -1 (two first lines), the first 4 columns and the 6th cannot have values below 0, and the 5th column cannot have values above 0. Maybe there are better ways to do this.